# Limit pressduration of keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard

I am looking for a way to reduce the time a key on my keyboard is pressed.

Atm when I press a key the avg is something around 80-130ms. I am looking for a way to cap that at like 50ms.

So when I press a key for 8ms it is pressed for 8ms. But when I press a key for 100ms I want it only be recognized for 50ms.

Any Ideas?